# The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'DAL.Tag' and 'System.Boolean'

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, exception

I created a Generic Repository class like below :

```
public abstract class Repository<TEntity, TIdentifier> : IRepository<TEntity, TIdentifier> where TEntity : class
{
    //TEntity is type of DBSet and TIdentifier is name of SQL Table's Id column
    protected Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        Context = context;
        DBSet = Context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

in this Class we have a method named `SelectAll` as the following :

```
[DataObjectMethod(DataObjectMethodType.Select, true)]
public IEnumerable<TEntity> SelectAll(IEnumerable<TIdentifier> ids, List<string> includeNavigationProperties = null)
{
    ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "entity");
    MemberExpression leftParam = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(parameter, typeof(TEntity).GetProperty(IdentifierColumn));
    Expression body = parameter;
    foreach (TIdentifier identifier in ids)
    {
        var rightParam = Expression.Constant(identifier);
        body = Expression.Or(body, Expression.Equal(leftParam, rightParam));//Exception
    }
    return (IEnumerable<TEntity>) DBSet.Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter));
}
```

As you can see I wanted to select all rows with Id column in `IEnumerable<TIdentifier> ids`. But the following exception has occurred:

> The binary operator Or is not defined for the types 'DAL.Tag' and 'System.Boolean'

Comment: Do you understand why that exception occurred? What is your specific problem that prevents you from completing your task?

Comment: @usr: As I found, I couldn't create the predicate properly. I don'n know how I can the predicate

Comment: What would `DAL.Tag || bool` mean? You are trying to create such an expression. This is clearly wrong and you should change that. Both operands need to be booleans.

Comment: Well, Could you please write a sample code, thanks.

Comment: ;-) Mohammed, what I'm trying to tell you is that nobody's doing your homework if you don't show any effort. All you do is ask for people to do all your work without you doing anything. Good luck with that.

Comment: Actually, I don't know how to write it. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you execute your logic on paper you'll get something like

1. Expression = Entity
2. Expression = Entity OR (parameter = ids[0]) OR (parameter = ids[1]) ...

probably not what you meant unless Entity happens to be a bool.